# Running vaultwarden docker-compose with caddy on https while openlitespeed webserver is running causing https issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, caddy, openlitespeed

I have installed Openlitespeed on my ubuntu 20.04 server, which works with http on port 80.

I ran a vaultwarden docker-compose.yml with caddy with HTTP Challenge which uses port 443 for https.
I used the docker-compose.yml and Caddyfile which was documented here https://github.com/dani-garcia/vaultwarden/wiki/Using-Docker-Compose.

Vaultwarden runs perfectly with my domain with https, but the caddy:2 container is now blocking port 443, which I need for https on my openlitespeed web server.

I tried to change the port in the docker-compose.yml for caddy to something other than 443, but then my web interface fails to load.

How can I run both my docker-compose and my web server with https? Can I use openlitespeed instead of caddy? What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

We can take advantage of [openlitespeed docker solution](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/docker/ols+wordpress/), but we still need to manually set up proxy settings since there's no existing OpenLiteSpeed as a Proxy Docker image for vaultwarden.

### Docker Setup

1.Download the ols-docker-env

```
git clone https://github.com/litespeedtech/ols-docker-env.git;
cd ols-docker-env
```

2.Edit the **docker-compose.yml** file to

```
version: '3'
services:
  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    container_name: vaultwarden
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WEBSOCKET_ENABLED=true
    volumes:
      - ./vw-data:/data

  litespeed:
    image: litespeedtech/openlitespeed:${OLS_VERSION}-${PHP_VERSION}
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
        - ./lsws/conf:/usr/local/lsws/conf
        - ./lsws/admin-conf:/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf
        - ./bin/container:/usr/local/bin
        - ./sites:/var/www/vhosts/
        - ./acme:/root/.acme.sh/
        - ./logs:/usr/local/lsws/logs/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 443:443/udp
      - 7080:7080
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: ${TimeZone}
```

3.Run the following command to start containers

```
docker-compose up -d
```

4.[Set password for OpenLiteSpeed](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/docker/ols+wordpress/#setting-the-webadmin-password)

```
bash bin/webadmin.sh my_password
```

Access the Web Admin at port 7080 from your browser and log in with the password you set.

### Follow [OLS as a reverse proxy setup](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/reverse-proxy-basics/) to set up OLS as a revere proxy

1.Go to Virtual Host Example > External App, create 2 Web Servers,
[image]

2.Go to Virtual Host Example > Rewrite
Set **Enable Rewrite** to `Yes`
Add following Rewrite Rules

```
RewriteRule /notifications/hub/ http://vaultwarden3012/ [P,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://vaultwarden80/$1 [P,L]
```

3.Go to Virtual Host Templates and remove un-used **docker** Template

4.Go to Listener > HTTP > Add Virtual Host Mappings
5.Go to Listener > HTTPS > Add Virtual Host Mappings
[image]

6.SSL Apply example
Access into the litespeedtech container and apply cert,

```
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d example.com -w /usr/local/lsws/Example/html
```

7.Add SSL key and cert to Virtual Host Example > SSL

- Private Key File: `/root/.acme.sh/certs/example.com/example.com.key`
- Certificate File: `/root/.acme.sh/certs/example.com/fullchain.cer`
- Chained Certificate: `Yes`

### Result

[image]

*Note: I have no experience with the vaultwarden app, feel free to let me know if I missed anything.*